# Java subsequent DB2 insertions -845 error

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, transactions, db2

I am getting -845 SQL codes on a table insert:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL
[INSERT INTO PIM30_POL_DETAILS VALUES(PREVIOUS VALUE FOR PIM_ORDER_ID_SEQ, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NULL)];
SQL state [51035]; error code [-845]; DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-845, SQLSTATE=51035, SQLERRMC=SHELTRU.PIM_ORDER_ID_SEQ, DRIVER=4.17.29; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-845, SQLSTATE=51035, SQLERRMC=SHELTRU.PIM_ORDER_ID_SEQ, DRIVER=4.17.29] with root cause
 com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-845, SQLSTATE=51035, SQLERRMC=SHELTRU.PIM_ORDER_ID_SEQ, DRIVER=4.17.29
```

The Java code for this is:

```
@Transactional
public String insertIntoDatabase(final List<Policy> pols, final InspectionOrder order, final OrderReason reason){
    String toReturn = PolicyDAO.transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public String doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
            SqlParameterSource params = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(order);
            PolicyDAO.namedParemeterJdbcTemplate.update(Queries.getInsertInspOrder(), params);

            for(Policy p : pols){
                params = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(p);
                PolicyDAO.namedParemeterJdbcTemplate.update(Queries.getInsertPolDetails(), params);
            }

            return "Successfully ordered inspection(s)";
        }
    });

    if(toReturn.equals("Successfully ordered inspection(s)")) return toReturn;
    else return "Failed to order inspection(s)";
}
```

Both INSERT statements use a sequence, the first one uses NEXT VALUE FOR PIM_ORDER_ID_SEQ and the second one uses PREVIOUS VALUE FOR PIM_ORDER_ID_SEQ. I presume that the second insertion is being called before the first insertion is finished as I only get the error 5-10% of the time.

What can I do to combat this?

Comment: How do you obtain the `Connection` used in `PolicyDAO`? I suspect that, if a connection pool is used, the inserts may be issued in different connections, and the sequence value has session (connection) scope, hence the error.

Comment: @mustaccio A javax.sql.DataSource object is passed into the namedParameterJdbcTemplate from the Tomcat's context.xml on app deployment. All connections are handled automatically as far as I know.

Comment: Well, you need to make sure that all calls to `namedParemeterJdbcTemplate.update()` use exactly the same `Connection` object. I don't know if `doInTransaction()` does that for you, probably not.